# How to dynamically load several images that are accessed by a curl command?

Tags: android, curl, picasso, android-glide

I have a List of Objects (already in a RecyclerView) and in each of the objects there's an image-id (String, could be null) that I can use to form a URL and get an image.

The problem is, I can only get the image with a GET curl command. I need to give an accessToken as a Header.

Is there a service like Glide or Picasso that would allow me to what I need to?

Answer (score 0):

In glide you can add custom header, set your access token in header as follows:

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl("url", new LazyHeaders.Builder()
 .addHeader("accessToken", "your-access-token-here")).build());

GlideApp.with(this).load(glideUrl).into(yourImageView);
```